# How to generate a RTL or a LTR version based on the html lang attribute when using postcss-rtl?

Tags: css, postcss

Recently I used postcss-rtl plugin to adapt the layout of RTL languages. But I found for each language the plugin would always generate 2 sets of styles, one for LTR and the other for RTL. In fact, only one is needed. For example, I don't need the RTL css styles when the language is en-US.

Although there is an `onlyDirection` option in `.postcssrc.js` for us to config, it can only receive `ltr` or `rtl` string explicitly. We couldn't dynamically pass a value based on the html `dir` attribute. My project set the `dir` attribute for html tag at runtime, but this plugin set the `onlyDirection` option when compiling, which happens before runtime. I don't quite sure if this is the reason why it is hard to generate a RTL or a LTR version dynamically.